# How to draw a triangle like this one

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a rectangle of size $x \times n$ and need to draw the line that bisects the corners as percentages of the rectangle.  The example plot shows a range from 0% to 100% in 5% increments.  Can this be done in *Mathematica*? [image]

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but at first blush, I'd probably plot an appropriately scaled `Floor[]` function and use the `Filling -> Axis` option. Constructing a direct `Polygon[]`, would be most efficient, but will require programming effort.

Comment: Quite a few ways to do this. Have a loot at `DiscretePlot`, also plotting unit steps or alternatively points with interpolation order->0 and the last two examples with filling to the axis. There should be examples of these here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
BarChart[
  Range[0, 100, 5],
  BarSpacing -> None,
  ChartStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Black]], 
  Axes -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Many more alternative approaches are available. For instance, you can build the graphics directives yourself, as J.M. suggested:

```
Graphics[
  Table[Rectangle[{n, 0}, {(n + 5), n}], {n, 0, 95, 5}],
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

... or use `DiscretePlot`, as Mike suggested:

```
DiscretePlot[x, {x, 0, 100, 5},
  ExtentSize -> Left,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0], Black],
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black],
  Axes -> False
]
```

Comment: The Graphics solution worked well.  Discrete plot adds a black line where 0 should be.  Thanks!

Comment: @RHall Yes `DiscretePlot` will draw an extent line even at zero; I also found that the extent line seems to slightly "overhang" the bar it corresponds to. It is the least visually pleasing result. `BarChart` seems to avoid that. Thanks for the accept as well!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution done with the help of `Riffle[]` and `ListLinePlot[]`

[image: diagram]

```
down = {0, 0} + # {1.5, 1} & /@ Range[0, 10];
up = {0, 1} + # {1.5, 1} & /@ Range[0, 9];
ListLinePlot[Riffle[down, up], Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: plot]

Another simple method I think is using `Floor[]` directly.

```
Plot[Floor[x], {x, 0, 15}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

```
ListStepPlot[Range[0, 100, 5], Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Black,
             PlotStyle -> Black, Ticks -> None, Axes -> False]
```

[image: result of ListStepPlot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
raggedTriangle[pmin_?VectorQ, pmax_?VectorQ, p_: 5] := 
      Module[{d = pmax - pmin, iv}, iv = Subdivide[#, 100/p] & /@ d;
             Polygon[Append[TranslationTransform[pmin] /@ 
                            Most[Riffle[Transpose[iv],
                                        Transpose[MapAt[RotateLeft, iv, 2]]]],
                            {First[pmax], Last[pmin]}]]]
```

An example:

```
Graphics[{{Blue, Rectangle[{1, 2}, {5, 3}]},
          {Orange, raggedTriangle[{1, 2}, {5, 3}, 10]}}]
```

[image: the steps go up and up]

Comment: I get the error "Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {Subdivide[4,10],Subdivide[1,10]} cannot be transposed.  In both 9 & 10

Comment: `Subdivide[]` first became available in version 10.1. A substitute for earlier versions would be `subdivide[xmax_: 1, n_Integer?Positive] := xmax Range[0, 1, 1/n]`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M.  Looks like I'll need to upgrade

Comment: Nevertheless, if you make the substitution I indicated, then there's no need for you to upgrade yet just for this simple thing. ;) Upgrade only if you want all the [other neat stuff](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) that came after 10.